# FirstOrDefault LINQ query with a condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am new to LINQ queries and want to use `FirstOrDefault` in my existing LINQ query.

```cs
List<vUserAll> employee = (from o in db.vUsersAll
  where (o.sAMAccountName == modifiedAccountName || o.CN == modifiedAccountName) && o.Domain == "dExample"
  select o).ToList();
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Can you please explain "wants to use firstordefault"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the above mentioned is the case, then you can use a labmda as in the following:

```
var firstOrDefaultResult = db.vUsersAll.Where(o=> 
(o.sAMAccountName == modifiedAccountName || o.CN == modifiedAccountName) 
&& o.Domain == "dExample").FirstOrDefault()
```

If you want to use the same above expression then,

```
vUserAll employee = (from o in db.vUsersAll
  where (o.sAMAccountName == modifiedAccountName || o.CN == modifiedAccountName) && o.Domain == "dExample"  
  select o).FirstOrDefaul();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot easier if you only use LINQ extensions. For example,

```
var filtered = all users.Where(u => u. Field == filter).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be simplified further as:

```
var filtered = db.vUsersAll.FirstOrDefault(u => u. Field == filter);
```